# How to load ng-walktrrough function on page load in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I'm pretty new to Ionic i just want to show an walktrough on my new ionic app but i'm not able to do it on page load i can invoke it on button click but i'm not able to get it on page load

Comment: You could `ng-init = "walkthrough()"` in the view to call the invoking function. Please post some relevant code and/or a verifiable example for better help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ionic 2 or higher refer "Lifecycle events" section in below link 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

Also you can make use of angular life cycle events https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks